# Lambert expression alternative form

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

According to wolframAlpha, after typing in e^LambertW(c ln n) it shows that's equal to $e^{W(c{\log(n))}}$, and the alternative form is $\frac{c{\log}(n)}{W(c{\log}(n))}$. How does this alternative form come about? I think a natural log and change of base was performed. But I'm kind of confused why $W(c{\log}(n))$ appears in the denominator and could the ${\log}$s be considered as ${\log_2}$?

Comment: Try $$\text W(x)e^{\text W(x)}=x\implies \frac x{\text W(x)}=e^{\text W(x)}$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the identities of the Lambert W function is:

$$W(x)e^{W(x)} = x$$

In our case $x = c\log{(n)}$ so,

$$W(c\log{(n)})e^{W(c\log{(n)})} = c\log{(n)}$$

$$e^{W(c\log{(n)})} = \frac{c\log{(n)}}{W(c\log{(n)})}$$

The $\log$s are all the same base so if $x = c \log_2(n)$ then the numerator and denominator of the quotient will also be of base 2. I don't know if you can switch the bases of the numerator and denominator to another base not used in the original $x$, will need some tinkering around with the maths to see if you can prove it, but I'm guessing no, but you can try disprove it empirically but just inserting some numbers.